# Find position of another device connected over Wifi with my device

Tags: android

I Need to find the location of devices which is connected with other devices over Same Wifi Network Via My App.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Our goal is to solve problems, not define solutions (that's your job)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004530/how-to-find-wifi-signal-direction-of-another-device-in-android?rq=1